# how to extract from list python, element with index multiple of 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to get those with the index that is a multiple of two

```
    code=[1,2,4,7,2,6,8]
    ncode=[code[i] for i%2==0]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions this way :

```
code=[1,2,4,7,2,6,8]
print [val for i,val in enumerate(code) if i%2==0]
```

`enumerate()` returns the index and value at the index, which is stored in `i` and `value` respectively.

For more details:

[list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 4):

Just use this indexing method:

```
code[::2]
```

If you want the odd index

```
code[1::2]
```

Generally, this is how it works:

```
seq = L[start:stop:step]

seq = L[::2] # get every other item, starting with the first
seq = L[1::2] # get every other item, starting with the second
```

Comment: mathmax, this is great. I just read about 'step' in list slicing. Can you please provide more information so that OP understands this and if he finds it better he might accept this.

Answer (score 0):

```
code = [1,2,4,7,2,6,8]
new_code = []

for i in range(0, len(code), 2):  ### iterate over even indexes
   new_code.append(code[i])

print new_code
```